# How to add a checkbox column to a ListView in WPF and get the state of it

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, listview, checkbox

I have a listview with the ItemsSource set to a the result of a linq query like this

```
listViewPlan.ItemsSource = new ObservableEvents(query);
```

The values of the result are bound to columns of the listView.
Now I'ld like to add another column containing a Checkbox so the user can select some of the items in the listview. So I added this

```
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding select}">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Tag="select"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <GridViewColumnHeader Click="SortClick" Tag="select" Content="" />
            </GridViewColumn>
```

This adds a Checkbox column to the listview. But it's not bound to anything from the linq result. So I can't access the current state of the Checkbox with listViewPlan.Items[i] . I also don't want to add a bool to the datatype from the database since the checkbox-states a single user has should not be stored anywhere globally. I could make another class that is similar to the linq class with a bool added for the Checkbox. But then I'ld have to copy all the member variables back and forth. How can I do this?

Comment: You can wrapper you object on a ViewModel, you expose your "database" object on the ViewModel in order to use the binding and create a Bool property to bind with the Checkbox

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiselect mode in listbox and bind CheckBox.IsChecked to ListViewItem.IsSelected.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemTemplate">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                                      AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" />
</DataTemplate>
```