# WPF&MVVM: Add controls to auto-generated List View

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to create the `List View` like this:

[image]

(Although the `List View` already has multi-select function and don't need the checkboxes, I want to add them for low-experience user who don't know what if to hold `Shift` key it's possible to select multiple items.)

Currently, my `List View` includes only `ID` and `Full Name` columns; the data displays by binding created according `MVVC` concept.

```
<ListView Name="DataTable" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=people}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="50px">
                <!-- This is column for checkboxes but it don't should be in header  -->
            </GridViewColumn>  
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PersonID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="FullName" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FullName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="50px">
                <!-- This is column for "Edit" buttons but it don't should be in header  -->
            </GridViewColumn>  
            <GridViewColumn Width="50px">
                <!-- This is column for "Delete" buttons but it don't should be in header  -->
            </GridViewColumn>  
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

How I can add the checkboxes and buttons in every not-header row?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756171/how-to-add-a-checkbox-column-to-a-listview-in-wpf-and-get-the-state-of-it

Comment: You are probably looking for [DataGridTemplateColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Clemens, looks like it is. I`ll try it. Thanks you for the reference!

Comment: @Filburt, the example code is empty xD Anyway it the Microsoft's fault. Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare a `CellTemplate` with a CheckBox:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="50px">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: It will! Thank you for the answer!